# What is the mechanism behind this command: . FILE

Tags: linux, shell

Why can I call the variables from file `/etc/os-release` in the shell after entering `. /etc/os-release`?

Example:

```
user@host:~$ echo $ID

user@host:~$ . /etc/os-release 
user@host:~$ echo $ID
ubuntu
user@host:~$
```

What is the name of this "`. FILE`"-mechanism? Where can I find more information?

Comment: Search for `source` in the bash man page.  Basically, `.` is the short/original/preferred name for `source`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thx, I found it here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins

Answer (score 1):

shell builtin command `. filename [arguments]`

> Read and execute commands from the `filename` argument in the current shell context.

The builtin `.` is equivalent to `source`.

`. filename` is equal to `source filename`

Man page:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins